When the session times out, a double click is required to go to the login page
I use this code. After setting passwordChanged, when I click (first request) then it invalidates the session in authenticationServices.logout(getHttpServletRequest()), and on the next request it goes to the login page (I have to double click to go to the login page). I want to go to login page when I click request for the first time after session invalidates.
public class LogOutAfterChangePasswordInterceptor extends BaseInterceptor {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5906534052815899264L;
        private static final Logger LOG = 
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogOutAfterChangePasswordInterceptor.class);
        private static final String ACTIONS_TO_REMEMBER = "static-password-setting-result";
        private static final String PASSWORD_CHANGED_FLAG = "passwordChanged";
        public static final String LOGIN = "login";
        @Inject
        private AuthenticationServices authenticationServices;
    
        @Override
        public String intercept (ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
            
            invocation.addPreResultListener((actionInvocation, resultCode) -> {
                HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();
                
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    
                if (getActionName().contains(ACTIONS_TO_REMEMBER)) {
                    LOG.trace("push URL `{}` that user after that should be logout ", 
                    ACTIONS_TO_REMEMBER);
                    session.setAttribute(PASSWORD_CHANGED_FLAG, true);
                } else {
                    Boolean passwordChanged = session != null ? (Boolean) 
                    session.getAttribute(PASSWORD_CHANGED_FLAG) : null;             
                    if (passwordChanged != null && passwordChanged) {
                        // Perform logout or other necessary actions
                        session.removeAttribute(PASSWORD_CHANGED_FLAG);
                        LOG.trace("User will be logged out after the next request");
                        try {
                            authenticationServices.logout(getHttpServletRequest());
                        } catch (ClientException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // logout spring manually
                        Authentication auth = 
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                        if (auth != null) {
                            new                          
                           SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(getHttpServletRequest(), 
                           getHttpServletResponse(),auth);
                        }
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);        
                    }
                }
            });                     
                
            return invocation.invoke();     
        }       
    }


The session is created by the servlet container and it is available in the action context when your interceptor is executing. You can get a session there and check its validaty. Double click is not required, you need to wait after the first click to see what's happened. May be to look into server logs to find some exception. Show your struts.xml.

Thank you for your response. It doesn't happen on the first click. I do not have exception in server logs.

I set passwordChanged  flag in session when I see static-password-setting-result action. Request after static-password-setting-result action, invalidate the session because of passwordChanged is true. when I send next request I go to login page. I want to login page when the first next request after static-password-setting-result action. Thank you for your guidance.

After you invalidate a session you cannot reuse it anymore, thus you should send a redirect result to the next action. Because you have a new session, you will go to the login page.

I would appreciate it if you could give me an example so I can better understand your point

In struts.xml I have : 
public-page
/


if I add invalidation session to first if instead of else, I get error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated

You have misunderstood how the HTTP session works. You code will work only if the current session is valid (However, you have to remove a preresult listener wrapped around a code). When the session expires or you invalidate a session when you did logout from the browser, the interceptor won't work as expected, because you didn't check a session for validity at the first.
You should change your code and add a check for validity of the session when you trying to get a current session. The validity of the session is provided by the servlet API when you call request.getSesdion(false). You can learn about it more if you read java httpsession is valid? question.
Hence, you should check a session variable at first and if it is not available, return to the LOGIN result.
@Override
public String intercept (ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception 
     HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
     if (session == null) 
        return LOGIN;
     ...


